# Should I change the title of my question to make the results more searchable?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

My question [Who is Sifter, and what is “the so-called Sifter flare”](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/33606/7982) exists only because the linked BBC news item wrote "Sifter flare" where it should have written **Seyfert flare**.

The BBC News article has since been fixed, so "Sifter" no longer appears anywhere, which makes me wonder if I should just update my question to read

> Who is Seyfert, and what is “the so-called Seyfert flare”?

The change might make the question and its authoritative answer appear in more searches which is a good thing, and [a search for " Seyfert flare"](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/search?q=+Seyfert+flare) shows no other posts that it could end up being duped to.

I can't think of any reasons not to update the question, except that it makes my [reference to](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/33606/who-is-sifter-and-what-is-the-so-called-sifter-flare#comment63735_33608) a previous BBC error [about the colliding of "large hadrons"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/454554/83380) less obvious. (They edited once but there are still two references to the collision of large hadrons with other things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My opinion is yes, change the title, but don't remove Sifter from the text post. Just add some language that it was originally phrased that way.

Comment: updated, thanks!